# How to Parse Complicated JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I need help as i want to parse the field num1, num2 and action in python from the json of a particular sid. Here is the JSON code. Please Help as i am a newbie.

```
{
    "contestants": [{
        "sid": "53d88ec46fb1721307f3a185",
        "u": {
            "_id": {
                "$id": "53d88ec46fb1721307f3a185"
            },
            "g": "M",
            "id": "536lleepkyhnowfh67elpucsq",
            "n": "Asif Khairani",
            "st": "asif-khairani-53d88ec4b24d8"
        },
        "cl": {
            "_id": {
                "$id": "51ff5d1370b17224520002dc"
            },
            "st": "tirpude-institute-of-management-education",
            "ti": "Tirpude Institute of Management Education",
            "n": "Brands",
            "cst": "brands",
            "r": null,
            "c": null
        },
        "ct": "nagpur",
        "tv": 124,
        "cf": 20,
        "picture": "http:\/\/images.iimg.in\/u\/53d88ec46fb1721307f3a185-190-190\/asif-khairani-53d88ec4b24d8.img",
        "action": "+",
        "voteText": "Votes",
        "num1": 6,
        "num2": 5
    }]
}
```

Comment: Mmm the problem is not what @mu無 is saying, the problem is how is formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to `import json` in your script/code and then put put all your JSON code between single quotes to make your JSON to be a string:

`raw_json = '{"contestants":[{"sid":"53d88ec46fb1721307f3a185","u":{"_id":{"$id":"53d88ec46fb1721307f3a185"},"g":"M","id":"536lleepkyhnowfh67elpucsq", "n":"Asif Khairani","st":"asif-khairani-53d88ec4b24d8"},"cl":{"_id":{"$id":"51ff5d1370b17224520002dc"},"st":"tirpude-institute-of-management-education","ti":"Tirpude Institute of Management Education","n":"Brands","cst":"brands","r":null,"c":null},"ct":"nagpur","tv":124,"cf":20,"picture":"http:\/\/images.iimg.in\/u\/53d88ec46fb1721307f3a185-190-190\/asif-khairani-53d88ec4b24d8.img","action":"+","voteText":"Votes","num1":6,"num2":5}]}'`

Once you have the JSON code in the variable `raw_json`  like a string you have to do:

```
parsed_json = json.loads(raw_json)
```

and you'll have the JSON code like a python dict, and can access to the fields like:

```
parsed_json['contestants']   # Get contenstants list
parsed_json['contestants'][0]  # Get first object in contestants list
```

or whatever you need!

Answer (score 1):

Use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module;

```
import json
myFile = open(youtJsonFile, 'r')
yourJsonText = myFile.read()
myFile.close()
myObject = json.loads(yourJsonText)
# Access your Json file by dict or lists python
print myObject['contestants'][0]['num1']
print myObject['contestants'][0]['num2']
```